# Testing elasticsearch API - how to make test data portable?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I recently built a python flask API that is backed by Elasticsearch. The API does a lot of filtering, sorting, searching, etc so I've added tests to ensure these features work. The way I test right now is to start a local version of Elasticsearch and Kibana using docker-compose. I uploaded my index templates, then pulled in 10,000 records for each of the five indeces I need to test.

When I run tests I start the local elasticsearch server, then test against the data that is in the server. This is working well and makes me feel fairly confident that things are working right. However, the test dataset is 'stuck' on a single computer and cannot be moved around easily. Anybody recommend one of the following ideas:

1. Use snapshot and restore to somehow set up another version of the server. Maybe I can store the latest snapshot in the repository?
2. Create and host a single test cluster and run tests against that
3. Create fixtures that I can somehow import when I start elasticsearch. This is how I would do things with postgresql, but I've not seen this for elasticsearch.

Right now I'm the main developer on this API, but I want to make tests somewhat portable. Would like to hear any ideas.

Comment: have you seen https://github.com/elasticsearch-dump/elasticsearch-dump? With the tool it is failry easy to dump the ES DB into a file and restore it back from file to ES. Depending on the size I would either put it in the repository (smaller) or save to S3 or else and load it within the pipeline or download locally for testing

Comment: @FloLie No I have not seen that but it's a great idea. Thank you!